# Devise Account Unlock Returning "Unlock Token is Invalid"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a standard devise implementation. Everything is working except for account unlocking (locking works fine).

I can unlock accounts in the console using `unlock_access!`. I can also locate the account using `User.find_by_unlock_token`. However, `UnlocksController#show` - specifically, `resource_class.unlock_access_by_token(params[:unlock_token])` - returns an *"Unlock token is invalid"* error.

Any help would be be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was a problem with a missed update to Devise. In the mailer template, `@resource.unlock_token` changed to `@token`. Works!

Comment: Thanks for the info I was looking for "unlock_access!"

Comment: Are you saying the old one was `@resource.unlock_token` and you needed to change it to `@token`? Or that you had changed it to `@token` and needed to change it back to `@resource.unlock_token` ?

Comment: I tried it both ways, and changing it from `@resource.unlock_token` to `@token` was the way that worked for me. Thanks!