# Rails, devise (4.2.0, 4.0.3) - Unlock token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is my `unlock_instructions.html.erb` code:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Your account has been locked due to an excessive number of unsuccessful sign in attempts.</p>

<p>Click the link below to unlock your account:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Unlock my account', unlock_url(@resource, unlock_token: @token) %></p>
```

I am getting this link by email: `http://my-corporate-care.herokuapp.com/users/unlock?unlock_token=YKBToxBnBYhfbtrC_5XH`

Which is giving me an error like in the picture.

[image]

Don't know how to fix it since my code looks updated based on other posts I fetched?

For comparison, forgot password link works.

Comment: What version is it? 4.2.0 or 4.0.3? Find the one you want and look into the controller: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.0.3/app/controllers/devise/unlocks_controller.rb and the model: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.0.3/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb. Add breakpoints if needed and troubleshoot.

Comment: Removed version 4.2.0 and kept version 4.0.3. Now unlock is working.

Comment: Upgraded to 4.1.0 and is working. Maybe 4.2.0 is not stable?

Comment: Update your question to include additional details? Clarify, that you are trying to upgrade, have you read the release notes? You shouldn't upgrade to minor versions without knowing what changed.

Comment: And it worked with 4.2.0 when using Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.3.0 but failed with Rails 5.0.0. and Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: All that sounds like many different questions to me.

Comment: Reading all specs for all gems to update / upgrade looks like a lot of reading to do and zero time to write to code.

Comment: It seems like the view template changed recently. Maybe it's related? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560976/devise-account-unlock-returning-unlock-token-is-invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to use this version of the gem.

```
devise (4.1.1)
```

The error disappeared.